# Array.prototype.forEach.call equivalent for objects

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an equivalent of this:

```
var myArr = [DOMElement, DOMElement];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(myArr, function(el, i) {
   el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('you clicked on element number ' + i);
   }, false);
});
```

The thing about this is you don't run into the addEventListener problem like you do here:

```
var myArr = [DOMElement, DOMElement];
for (var i=0; i<myArr.length; i++) {
   myArr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('you clicked on element number ' + i);
   }, false);
}
```

in the second case anytime you click on an element it will always say you clicked on the last i.

So I was wondering how to loop through an object and its keys while being able to safely use addEventListener. So like:

```
var myObj = {blahKey: DOMElement};
for (var k in myObj) {
   myObj[k].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('you clicked on element with key = ' + k)
   }, false);
}
```

Comment: `i` is the index here, so it should work. Is this all the code. Remember the order of `Array.prototype.foreach`'s callback is: value, index, originalArray

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `forEach`, I assume you're safe with ES5. You can use `Object.keys` to return an array of keys from an object. Then use `forEach` on it.

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key,i){
  myObj[key].addEventListener(...);
});
```

Do note that the order of the keys returned by `Object.keys` is the same case for `for-in` loops. It doesn't guarantee the same order across browsers. If order does matter, I suggest you stick with arrays instead.

Comment: @AvinashBabu You can actually delete the comment :D

Comment: Super idea thanks! Other guy posted at same time saying same solution haha so Ill just up vote both you and leave no solution checked :P

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys and then use `forEach` as usual, like this

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(k) {
   myObj[k].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('you clicked on element with key = ' + k)
   }, false);
});
```

Comment: Correct answer, just noting requires ES5.

Comment: Super idea thanks! Other guy posted at same time saying same solution haha so Ill just up vote both you and leave no solution checked :P